# Kids book where a boy is captured by a witch

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

Looking for a picture kids book where a farm boy gets captured by a witch. She rolls out dough the length of him to make him into a sandwich. At night her body detaches. Her arms go lay by the fire place, her body stays on the rug, her legs go in the corner, and her head goes somewhere else. The boy runs away and the body parts chase him but he’s escapes and makes it home.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  How did the body parts chase him?  Did they fly?

Comment: Sounds like Grandpa's Ghost Stories by Jim Flora. https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/34381101